# Google Denying Request for Sensitive GMail Scope

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

About 3 months ago I got an email from Google telling me their rules for using sensitive scopes for GMail changed.  Now virtually all GMail scopes are "sensitive".

My application (which runs on an IBM i system, in the past know an iSeries, AS/400, etc) was using:

https://mail.google.com/

So once I got that, I did some research and found out the least common scope I required was:

/auth/gmail.modify

This was mainly so that a user could mark a message as "read" after downloading email to their system.

The application is used to download emails from their account and process the emails, attachments and other parts.

Well, Google and I went back and forth with what seemed like robotic emails from Google asking for this and that, videos that show the OAuth authentication, use of the app, etc.  I provided everything they asked.  Of course each reply took 2-3 weeks each time.

They asked for the videos again making sure the client ID was in the video for OAuth Authentication.  I did that again, and in the video paused and highlighted this information.

After about 3 rounds of "we're sorry, your video is insufficient, please provide another one" I pleaded to speak to someone on the phone or directly as this isn't a normal app on a phone/device.  It's on a mainframe system used by businesses that doesn't have a native browser available.  The authentication starts on a traditional "terminal/green screen" and then takes over from a URL on my site (using HTTPS all the way through).

Well, today they turned down the request stating it didn't meet their specifications, but of course no other explanations.  I have read their rules many times and I don't see where they are coming from.

How can I have a reasonable conversation with a huge company if they don't even understand the system it's run on and different that every other app?

I imagine the response is "they can do what they want".  But this is sort of ridiculous and I'm sure the person reviewing it didn't know what they were watching.

Here are the videos if anyone wants context:

The First video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6Ips7eOqbs) I showed CLEARLY the client ID and setting up OAuth 2.0 for user.

The 2nd video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1v_ledW4cQ) shows how it retrieves messages and parts, marks them as read (which requires the modify scope).

Comment: I just realized the scope https://mail.google.com/ is also required for OAuth 2.0 authentication using Googles SMTP server as well.  That is a recent as February 2019 in their documentation.  Is this an example of the right hand not knowing what the left is doing?  I remember a few years ago I was able to get in contact with someone at Google fairly easily to report their expired SSL CAs for the serverrs (happened 2 years in a row).  But now this?  I don't understand them not allowing the use of almost all gmail scopes for developers, especially those of us creating solutions for businesses.

Comment: Based on what you shared, I see two issues. Firstly, your first video doesn't show the entire `client_id`. That's easy to fix: you should expand your browser window to display the entire thing. I made a sample [video with some tips here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evD9X34Ahus)...

Comment: Also, [Google recently promoted all GMail scopes from "Sensitive" to "Restricted"](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/elevating-user-trust-in-our-api.html). This is a major change that restricts the types of applications that are allowed to use the data as well as the process for verifying apps that may qualify to use these scopes.

Review the [Restricted Scope App Verification section of the OAuth Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#restricted-scopes) to determine which category your app falls into.

Comment: I highlighted it in video.  Why would I hide purposely the id? If that was the issue I would have hoped they would have said that was the issue. I think they overlooked the fact that the SMTP server, when using OAuth 2.0 authentication, requires the most sensitive and encompassing scope.  So, still looking for ideas.  I did resubmit explaining it's required for SMTP.  PS - They also asked me a lot of questions that proved to me they had NO idea the platform this was on.  Which is why I requested many times to speak with someone one on one instead of the boilerplate questions.